# How to decode html miscellaneous symbol from its glyph?

Tags: javascript, html, jasmine

I have a div that contains a settings icon that is a html miscellaneous symbol

```
<span class="settings-icon">&#9881;</span>
```

I have a jasmine test that checks the div contents to makes sure that it is not changed.

```
  it("the settings div should contain &#9881;", function() {
    var settingsIconDiv = $('.settings-icon');
     expect(settingsIconDiv.text())
       .toContain('&#9881;');
  });
```

It will not pass as it is evaluated as its glyph symbol of a gear icon ⚙

How to I decode the glyph in order to pass the test?

Comment: To match the browser behavior (because you don't know how it is encoded in `html` or in `text`) i would try the following `.toContain($("<span>&#9881;</span>").text())` instead of `.toContain('&#9881;')`. That way it _should_ match how it is stored in the dom.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, add that as an answer

Comment: How about `.toContain(String.fromCharCode(9881))` ?

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter - it passes now, add that in as answer please, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get actual character from Unicode to compare it to a literal in HTML you can use [String.fromCharCode()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp) e.g.

```
.toContain(String.fromCharCode(9881))
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I get the below error:-
Expected 'â' to contain 'â'.

Jasime spec: 
`expect(element.text()).toContain(String.fromCharCode(9881))`

My HTML is, 
`<span> &zwnj;</span>`

Comment: My bad, it works. I was using the wrong UTF-16 value

Answer (score 2):

You should check against the string `'⚙'` or, if you do not how to enter it in your code, the escape notation `\u2699`. There are other, clumsier ways to construct a string containing the character, but simplicity is best.

No matter how the character is written in HTML source code (e.g., as the reference `&#9881;`), it appears in the DOM as the character itself, U+2699. In JavaScript, a string like `&#9881;` is just a sequence of seven Ascii characters (though you can pass it to a function that parses it as an HTML character reference, or you can assign it e.g. to the `innerHTML` property, causing HTML parsing, but this is rather pointless and confusing).

Comment: Tried with using the escape notation but I get an error -  Expected 'â' to contain 'â'. Jasime spec: expect(element.text()).toContain('\u2699') My HTML is, <span> &zwnj;</span>

Comment: My bad, it works. I was using the wrong UTF-16 value.

Answer (score 1):

To match the browser behavior (because you don't know how it is encoded in html or in text) i would try the following

`.toContain($("<span>&#9881;</span>").text())` instead of `.toContain('&#9881;')`.

That way it *should* match how it is stored in the dom.

The `String.fromCharCode(9881);` mentioned by `Yuriy Galanter` will definitely also work reliable. But because dom engine and the js engine are two different parts, that could behave differently, i would test with both techniques.